# why does the files inside the gvfs-metadata directory remains open after tor is closed

Tags: log

running lsof I can see some open files inside the tor directory.

specifically:

```
tor-browser_en-US/Browser/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home-xxxxxx.log

tor-browser_en-US/Browser/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home
```

why are these files open if tor isn't running ?

Comment: It's probably the gvfs-metadata daemon (`pgrep gvfsd-metadata`) that's keeping them open, not Tor Browser.

Answer (score 0):

LSOF is a handy tool, but it needs the user to understand what it writes: Tor itself is not using these files at all - they are even not used by the Tor browser *directly* - only through a service component. To make sure that everything **is** closed after you've closed Tor - use virtual machines and power them off after finishing the things you do through Tor